# Change service principal owner to group

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to change the owner of an Azure AD service principal after it has been created? And can it be changed to a group that should own the SP?

When creating with `az ad sp create-for-rbac` it doesn't allow you to specify the owner.

I'd like to change the owner for a SP to a different AD principal (group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this [is not a current feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/37337278-add-group-as-owner-on-azure-ad-application-and-ser). Another relevant discussion is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9250).